# How do I remove the Exception Error in running flutter?

Tags: flutter

```
fetchData()async{
    res = await  http.get(api);
```

**Exception has occurred.
HandshakeException (HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
    CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: self signed certificate in certificate chain(handshake.cc:352)))**

```
    print(res.body);
    drinks = jsonDecode(res.body)["drinks"];
    setState(() {
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error log clearly states that the error is not from flutter app side for api implementation.

Error is from web api side.

Contact your api person to resolve the server side issue.

Also try adding the internet permission in your manifest file,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Then, in your terminal run the following command,

```
flutter clean
```

If it doesn't work i don't think any issues are from flutte side.